# How to replace the WHERE clause with variable string?

Tags: vba, adodb

I'm trying to change the WHERE clause with variable string that passed from private subs into the sq string function. here's my code and i want to change the WHERE clause with the xref as stated in the code.
The xref changes according to the selected items from ComboBox1 or ComboBox2.
ComboBox1 refines column A and ComboBox2 refines Column B

Please let me know if anything not clear. Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Private Function test(ByRef xref As String, VTra As String)
Dim conn, rs As Object, sq As String

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

sq = "SELECT T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D] " & _
  "FROM [Data$] T1 " & _
  "WHERE T1.[A] IN ('" & VTra & "') " & _
  "GROUP BY T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D]"' Replace the WHERE clause with xref
      
               Set rs = conn.Execute(sq)
               
           With Me.ListBox
            .Value = ""
            .Column = rs.GetRows
                 End With
                 
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim xref As String
VTra = ComboBox1.Value
xref = "WHERE T1.[A] IN ('" & VTra & "')"
VTra = test(xref, ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim xref As String
VTra = ComboBox2.Value
xref = "WHERE T1.[B] IN ('" & VTra & "')"
VTra = test(xref, ComboBox2.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run this code? Also, you've created `test` as a function but it doesn't return a value.

Comment: When I replace it with xref, it doesn't read it as a full string. I created that as a dummy as the actual code it quite long.

Comment: Seems your code is not that clean: 1. You ware not using xref. 2. Everything is called VTra. 3. At teh end you pass only one value to the IN of the where. Maybe it is good to clean up so we understand the intent better.

Comment: Try to use this: xref = "WHERE T1.[B] IN (""" & VTra & """)"

Comment: and how the xref will look in the sq statement?

Comment: sq = "SELECT T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D] " & _
      "FROM [Data$] T1 " & _
       xref
      "GROUP BY T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D]" ??

Comment: Simply concatenate as string instead of the line. Instead "WHERE T1.[A] IN ('" & VTra & "') " place xref

Comment: as *bugdrown* said, your *test* doesn't return a value, and `VTra = test(...)` will be an error or meanless. `sq = "SELECT T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D] " & _
  "FROM [Data$] T1 " & _
  "WHERE T1.[A] IN ('" & VTra & "') " & _
  "GROUP BY T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D]"` ⇒ `sq = "SELECT T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D] " & _
  "FROM [Data$] T1 " & _
  xref & _
  "GROUP BY T1.[A],T1.[B],T1.[C],T1.[D]"`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @OscarSun  This is exactly what I meant and thank you for that! Ignore the coding and the test function, I just wanted to show you where I was stuck which is, by replacing the line WHERE........ with xref and concatenating the group by clause in the next line.  when I placed xref & _ as you stated it. It worked :), mine had a " before xref that's why it didn't work.

Comment: So is it all solved? Congratulations!

Comment: Yes, all solved.Thank you!